# M2 | Cron is not auto executing on server

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, cronjobs

I created custom cron job, all jobs are running fine on local server but on staging jobs are scheduled but always stay pending or missed.

I can execute cron from backend using third party extension and every time I click button "Run Cron" to execute all jobs (default, custom) and pending states are created..

Is there some setting we need to build cron for server and then all jobs will be auto creating..? like

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron

Comment: Check whether there is an entry for your website in **`crontab -e**

Comment: As DevDocs are stating: you should check:

crontab -l

A sample follows: * * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log

That should be you a hint, if you have Cron Jobs configurred to be executed on the Server